# Could I use Trident library to generate the absorption spectrum of atoms/molecules like carbon

Tags: spectrum, trident

Hi I wanted to find the absorption spectrum of different elements/molecules of the periodic table and I found that [Trident](https://trident.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) can simulate spectrums (I would prefer real spectrums in a .fit format) and I want to ask if there I could do it with that. Anyone has done anything with that library.

I just want to know if it's possible or not.

Thanks for reading